# Opening links to facebook and linkedin from bootstrap site

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Trying out bootstrap for first time.I have 2 social icons ,facebook and linkedin.I want to go to these pages when icons clicked But when I click on them they open to the index page of my site not facebook or linkedin.

```
   <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-bottom"  role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-text pull-left">
                 <p>Copyright &copy; Name 2016</p> 
        </div>
         <div class="navbar-text pull-right">
              <a    href "http://www.linkedin.com/pub/Name/36/797/981/" target="_blank">
                <i class="fa fa-linkedin-square fa-2x"></i></a>
                 <a  href "https://www.facebook.com/pages/Name/868408657863139?sk=info&=page_info/" target="_blank">
                  <i class="fa fa-facebook-square fa-2x"></i></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you forgot after href sign '=' :))

```
<a href = "http://www.linkedin.com/pub/Name/36/797/981/" target="_blank">
    <i class="fa fa-linkedin-square fa-2x"></i>
</a>
```

it's must be work